# Exception At "main" java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

```
[
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution 
{
static double rounnd(double r)
{
    double t=r;
    double x = Math.round(t*100);
    x=x/100;
    t=x;
    return t;
}

public static double op(int w,String sent,double t2) throws Exception
{
    String left="qwert",right="yuiop";
    int lt=1,rt=1,lastturn=0;

    double t3=0;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

    lt=1;rt=1;lastturn=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < sent.length();j ++)
    {
        left="qwert";right="yuiop";
        t2=0;
        lt=lastturn==1?lt:1;
        rt=lastturn==2?rt:1;
        char ch = sent.charAt(j);
        if (left.contains(Character.toString(ch))){
            t3=t3+(0.2*lt);
            lt=lt*2;
            lastturn=1;

        }
        else if (right.contains(Character.toString(ch))){
            t3=t3+(0.1*rt);
            rt=rt*2;
            lastturn=2;

        }

    }
    return t3;
}

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

    String left="qwert",right="yuiop";
    int lt=1,rt=1,lastturn=0;

    double t2[],t3[];
    String sent[];

    //System.out.println("Enter Numumber Of lines");
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    int w[]=new int[t];
    t2=new double[t];
    t3=new double [t];
    sent = new String[t];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){            
        w[i]=sc.nextInt();
        //br.readLine();
        sent[i] = br.readLine();
        t2[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        t3[i]=(0.3*(w[i]-1));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        String arr[]=sent[i].split(" ");
        String c[]=new String[arr.length];
        for(int j=0;j<w[i];j++)
            c[j]="";
        int r=0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length ; j ++){
            boolean b=false;
            for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++)//were tyui owiq 5.9 qwer yuio qiwo 5.1 type type were type were type 7.5
            {
                if(c[k].equals(arr[j]))
                    b=true;

            }
            if(b)
            {
                double q=(op(w[i],arr[j],t2[i])/2);
                t3[i]=t3[i]+q;
            }
            else {
                double q=op(w[i],arr[j],t2[i]);
                t3[i]=t3[i]+q;
            }
            c[r++]=arr[j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        t3[i]=rounnd(t3[i]);
        String str=String.valueOf((t3[i]));
        str=(str.length()-str.indexOf("."))==3?str:str+"0";
        System.out.println((t3[i]<t2[i]?"WORK HARDER, "+str:t3[i]==t2[i]?"GOOD, "+str:t3[i]>t2[i]?"GREAT JOB, "+str:""));

    }
}
}][1]
```

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/iiitv-bitsetgo-18/challenges/can-you-even-type
for error see the image code is there link to question is there please help there is some kind of exception occuring the program runs perfectly on bluej idk what happens on website https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOnc6.png . ***IGNORE THE AHEAD TEXT*** I don't know how much I need to type to qualify for the submission of my question coz I've already provided all the details. Idk what I typed.

Comment: Please don't make your question rely on outside resources. Question should be able to stay on its own even if linked resources will break. So please include in your question what your code is *supposed to do*, what data was used, and what did you get instead. Also don't post text as image. Purpose of this site it so let others with same problem find similar questions but search engines don't allow users to find text in image in question (at least not popular ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()

> InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float
>   regular expression, or is out of range

In this line you attempt to read a double using the `Scanner`

`sent[i] = br.readLine();`

Yet, the picture you attached shows that the provided input can be an integer or even a string. It seems that you never check whether the input you receive is a double or even numerical. I suggest you work on that.

Also a sidenote, this is extremely wrong for many many reasons. Please avoid doing that:

`sent = new String[t];`